# PHP Parse error - unexpected $end

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, parsing

I have the following code, and it's giving me a parse error when run.  Am I missing something obvious?

http://pastebin.com/FXxEgUB3

Sorry - here's the full error. It says on line 102, but that's after the last tag..

```
 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /var/www/cdr/outgoing_cdr.php on line 102
```

---

I see the unclosed bracket, got that, fixed the variable issues, now it's getting much further, but am seeing these errors now:

```
[Wed May 25 10:14:34 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/cdr/outgoing_cdr.php on line 53
[Wed May 25 10:14:34 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] PHP Warning:  mssql_query() [<a href='function.mssql-query'>function.mssql-query</a>]: message: Could not find stored procedure 'Array'. (severity 16) in /var/www/cdr/outgoing_cdr.php on line 53
[Wed May 25 10:14:34 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] PHP Warning:  mssql_query() [<a href='function.mssql-query'>function.mssql-query</a>]: Query failed in /var/www/cdr/outgoing_cdr.php on line 53
[Wed May 25 10:14:34 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/cdr/outgoing_cdr.php on line 53
[Wed May 25 10:14:34 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant salesrep - assumed 'salesrep' in /var/www/cdr/outgoing_cdr.php on line 90
[Wed May 25 10:14:34 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant repid - assumed 'repid' in /var/www/cdr/outgoing_cdr.php on line 91
[Wed May 25 10:14:34 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] PHP Warning:  mssql_query() [<a href='function.mssql-query'>function.mssql-query</a>]: message: Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ','. (severity 15) in /var/www/cdr/outgoing_cdr.php on line 97
[Wed May 25 10:14:34 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] PHP Warning:  mssql_query() [<a href='function.mssql-query'>function.mssql-query</a>]: Query failed in /var/www/cdr/outgoing_cdr.php on line 97
```

Line 53 has the foreach statement:

```
foreach (mssql_query($sqla) as $sqla_res) {
    if (!$sqla_res)
    {
            die('Query (1) failed.');
    } elseif (mssql_fetch_rows($sqla_res)==1)
    {
        $sqlares = $sqla_res;
        $found = mssql_fetch_array($sqla,MSSQL_BOTH);
        $clid = $found[clientid];
    } elseif (mssql_fetch_rows($sqla_res)==0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Line 97 is running this query:

```
INSERT INTO $table (extension, phonenumber, calldatetime, callID, name, repID, clientID, subscribed ) VALUES ($extension, $phonenumber, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $callID, $name, $repid, $clid, $subs)
```

Comment: I think you forgot the closing bracket of the else statement on line 77

Comment: on which line you are getting it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `$subs = $subs_f[subscribed];` and add a `}` just after.

A little tip, change your error_reporting to `E_ALL`, see how many issues you actually have!

Foreach Fix:

```
$resource = mssql_query($sqla);
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($resource))
{
     echo $row['column']; //This is an example
}
```

Comment: See line 2 - error_reporting(E_ALL); :)

Comment: So do you get errors say **constant not defined subscribed assuming "subscribed"**

Comment: @RobertPitt - No, see above for new errors

Comment: Om not going to fix your code for you but i will say, when your accessing an array, and looking for a strnig index, you should wrap in single quotes, so `$array['index']` to tell php that your searching with a string !

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  What am I doing wrong with the foreach(), though?

Comment: Change to a while, see above!

Answer (score 0):

```
} else {
        $sql_subs = "SELECT subscribed FROM $tbl_mkt WHERE clientid = $clid";
        $subs_res = mssql_query($sql_subs);
        if (!$subs_res) {
            die('Query (2) failed.');
        } else {
                $subs_f = mssql_fetch_array($sqla,MSSQL_BOTH);
                $subs = $subs_f[subscribed];
}
```

The second else block has no closing curly brace.

Comment: Closed this, now see new, unrelated errors.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Close the opened braсket after line 79.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I notice:

- `else` starting at line # 77 has no closing brace `}` (reason of your error)
- On line # 99 instead of `if (!$sql)` you probably meant to have `if (!$result)`

Comment: thanks, got those both.  Also mis-called $cidnumber; should have been $phonenumber.